# grep multiple files get count of unique cut

Tags: unix, grep

I think I'm close on this, and saw similar questions but couldn't get it to work as I want. So, I have several log files and I would like to count the occurrences of several different service calls by date.

First I tried the below, the cut is just to get the first element (date) and 11th element (name of service call), which is specific to my log file:

```
grep -E "invoking webservice" *.log* | cut -d ' ' -f1  -f11 | sort | uniq -c
```

But this returned something that looks like:

```
5 log_1.log:2017-12-05 getLegs()  
10 log_1.log:2017-12-05 getArms()  
7 log_2.log:2017-12-05 getLegs()
13 log_2.log:2017-12-04 getLegs()
```

What I really want is:

```
12 2017-12-05 getLegs()  
10 2017-12-05 getArms()
13 2017-12-04 getLegs()
```

I've seen examples where they cat * first, but looks like the same problem.

```
cat * | grep -E "invoking webservice" *.log* | cut -d ' ' -f1  -f11 | sort | uniq -c
```

What am I doing wrong? As always, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that `grep` prefixes the matched lines with the filenames. (`grep` has this behavior when multiple filenames are specified, to disambiguate the results.) You can pass the `-h` to `grep` to not print the filenames:

```
grep -h "invoking webservice" *.log | cut -d ' ' -f1  -f11 | sort | uniq -c
```

Note that I dropped the `-E` flag, because it is used to enable extended regex support, and your example doesn't need it.

Alternatively, you could use `cat` to dump the content of files to standard output, and pipe that to `grep`. That would work, because it removes the need for filename parameters for `grep`:

```
cat *.log | grep "invoking webservice" | cut -d ' ' -f1  -f11 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: lol so simple, thanks. Need to read up on the documentation. Thanks!